# Specification Attribute Filters Behavior

Tags: nopcommerce

I am working with NopCommerce. The Store I was asked to make has approximately 500,000 products and several hundred attributes.

In reference to this [demo](https://demo.nopcommerce.com/notebooks)

When you load a category, you get specific filters. When you select a filter however, the filters do not update in relation to what the first filter, filtered.

---

For example, if a store has 2 items:

Item 1: Specification Attributes (color: red, size: 4x3)
Item 2: Specification Attributes (color: blue, size: 6x3)

You would get the following filters:

color: red, blue
size: 4x3, 6x3

If I select color red in filters, then it would be logical to have the attribute filter "6x3" to not be presented.

---

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the filters to update when a filter is selected?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.